# Use of % modulo function

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulo

going through a tutorial I've learnt that the modulus function returns the remainder of the equation. Thus, for example, `3 % 4` equals 3

But I don't seem to understand how `25 * 3 % 4 = 3`. What's happened to 25?

I've run the script on PowerShell as well as online Google calculator, returns the same. Anyone willing to explain this, kindly?

Comment: read aloud from left to right :)

Comment: I have figured it out. Lol. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I'm sure though it's only us old C programmers that know that * / and % all have equal precedence.

Comment: @bathsheba I'm still new to this, maybe one day I'll get to say it as you.

Answer (score 5):

Since `*` and `%` have exactly the same *precedence*, *associativity* comes into play. Since both operators are evaluated from left to right (i.e. the *associativity* is from left to right), your expression is equivalent to

`(25 * 3) % 4`

which is, of course, `75 % 4` which is *also* 3.

Comment: That is 75%4, which is 18 remainder 3.